UK Visa Innocent mistakes
I applied for the UK visa, it was refused, in that application I made an error regarding the salary. I ammend it in the later application that was approved. My question is do I have mention this again and submit the same documents I submitted with my previous application even though I had cleared that up?
I anyway have to mention that refusal so I don't how to write that up, so I just leave it and mention my visa was refused or do I write the whole explanation again?

Was the salary the only issue with the first application? Was this a big error? Do you have documentation to back up the corrected value? Did you submit the same documentation with the first application? Please edit the question to include this information. Also please include a copy of the first application refusal notice, with personal information blacked out.

You may also find answers to this question edifying.


do I have mention this again?i

Yes. You have to mention the original refusal in all future UK visa applications that ask about such things.

do I write the whole explanation again?

No. There’s no need to go into huge detail to explain it given that you say you’ve had a visa approved subsequent to the refusal. Provide a copy of the original refusal letter if you have it.

…and submit the same documents I submitted with my previous application even though I had cleared that up?

No. UKVI will have a record of your previous application documents. For a new application, just submit the documents relevant to your situation now.

ok, thank you, I will just mention it in one line, along with the refusal letter. I think that should be okay.
